# Which related films do I need to watch before watching Avengers Assemble?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, the-avengers, prequels

I am going to watch "The Avengers", and I was wondering do I need to have watched any of the films such as Thor, Iron Man, Captain America etc to understand Avengers?

Comment: The Sci-Fi site had this question a few weeks ago.  [Which films should I see before “The Avengers”?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/16080/63)

Comment: I actualy like this question a little bit more than the sci-fi one.  The sci-fi one just asks "should i watch any of the other movies?", this question asks "Which ones should I watch in order to understand what's going on in Avengers?"

Comment: You need to read the comic books first. I am surprised nobody suggested that.

Answer (score 10):

**Blatantly [lifted](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1883/1027) from the [linked](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2618/which-related-films-do-i-need-to-watch-before-watching-avengers-assemble#comment3953_2618) [Sci-fi & Fantasy.SE](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) [question's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/16184/1027)**:

---

**Skipable**

- *Iron Man* and *Iron Man 2* are, IMO, the best movies in the current Marvel film universe. They are also not very important to understand what's going on in *The Avengers* - if you understand that Tony Stark is a brilliant jerk and has a robot suit, that's about all you need to know. *2* has Black Widow, but she's not really **introduced** until *The Avengers*.
- *The Incredible Hulk* is completely missable if you're even slightly familiar with the Hulk character. It's an average action movie, hardly alluded to during *The Avengers*, and it's not even the same actor between the two.

**Nice to See**

- *Captain America*'s backstory is used often for humor and occasionally for drama. If you don't see it you'll probably miss or barely catch a lot of the jokes in the first half.

**Important**

- *Thor* is mandatory - *The Avengers* is almost *Thor 2*. The main antagonist of *The Avengers* is the antagonist in *Thor*. A scientist in *Thor* is also a character in *The Avengers* and is given absolutely no introduction or explanation; if you want to understand the character dynamics in any of the scenes with him, you'll have to see *Thor*.

Comment: +1 Good answer (even if not yours). I also think they're all worth watching because of being good and entertaining movies (yes, I really liked *Captain America*), *The Incredible Hulk* maybe to a lesser degree.

Answer (score 1):

Iron Man, Iron Man 2 and Thor are definitely mandatory see as their the starting point for too of the Avengers and the main villain Loki.